# Changing tintColor on UIBarButtonItem in UIToolbar causes button to disappear and animate in from left

Tags: ios, ios5, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I'm using Xcode 4.2 to develop an iOS 5 app.

In Storyboard I've got a view with a UIToolbar, and 3 items in it. The last item is a UIBarButtonItem. I want to change the tintColor of this UIBarButtonItem when a user taps it, until what it does is dismissed.

I've made the UIBarButtonItem an outlet in my controller, here's the code:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *upArrowButton;
...
@synthesize upArrowButton = _upArrowButton;
```

...and I am changing the tintColor like so:

```
self.upArrowButton.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

However when the tintColor changes, the button disappears, and a new one (with the correct new tintColor) animates on screen from the left.

Any idea what mistake I've made?

UPDATE:

I've tracked down the source of the problem, it's because the method where tintColor was changed is called inside an animateWithDuration animations block.

Comment: You should post your resolution as an answer so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of this peculiar behaviour was because I was calling the method that changed the tintColor from within an animateWithDuration animations block. Thus causing the change in tintColor to be 'animated'.